# how to run single code structure for appium automation for both android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, appium

I am working on the project of Appium test automation for both android and IOS, where I've define some configuration and the runTests.xml file.
My concern is to use to single code structure for both android and IOS.

Right now, the configuration I made, only works for android, It is not working for iOS platform.

Please check the pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MW_TestAutomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>MW_TestAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MW_TestAutomation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <appium.version>5.0.0-BETA4</appium.version>
        <selenium.version>3.3.1</selenium.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <testng.version>6.14.3</testng.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <suiteXmlFile>runTests.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>${appium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <platform>${platform}</platform>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version> <!-- or whatever current version -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/com/mw/configs</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the mvn command is **mvn clean test -Dplatform=android -DsuiteXmlFile=runTests.xml**

and the runText.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="MW_Test_Automation">

    <!-- Login Page test scenarios -->
    <test name="LoginPageTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mw.tests.LoginPageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <!-- Dashboard Page test scenarios -->
    <test name="DashboardPageTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mw.tests.DashboardPageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <!-- Gauge Page test scenarios -->
    <test name="GaugePageTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mw.tests.GaugePageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Please let me know How can I perform automation for both android and ios with this configuration?